# Already Aristotle observed that

Tags: time-words

For those who knows Russian here is [my original question](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/16867/%D0%95%D1%89%D1%91-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5#16868). The question is as follows: is there any other way to express temporal relations, that is to say that something has already been around since X times? Some other adverb perhaps?

My fault—I've asked not what I meant to. The question is not only to express temporal relations but also to express the past time in an explicit relationship with the present or, more precisely, the other way around = the present to the past and to emphasize that mentioning the very person who already did it then in the past: *It was already observed by Aristotle that...* something along these lines.. [This comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/174011/already-aristotle-observed-that?noredirect=1#comment347063_174011) is the closest to what I meant to ask.

**Already in Aristotle's times it was observed that...** I think this is the best variant. No perfect is needed, the simple past will do.

Comment: This is a very broad question. There are quite a few ways of expressing the fact that a notion or idea is not  novel but has been around for ages.  Your sentence fragment with "already" in the title to the question is not idiomatic.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo  OK, that's even more interesting! I guess you understand what I'm trying to convey. So, what is an idiomatic way to express it concisely?

Comment: *The Mayans had already made significant astronomical discoveries long before the advent of the telescope.*  When referring to something in relation a past point, as earlier than that point, use past perfect + **already**. When referring to something in relation to the present, use present perfect + **already**.

Comment: You can say *Already Aristotle had observed ...* but it would be in relation to some other point in the past, e.g. in some history of science where the topic was, say, a late Roman work on natural history.  It would not be in relation to now, and it would **not** mean "this idea we have has been around for a very long time". It would mean "this idea those late Romans had..."

Comment: And although it would be perfectly grammatical to say *Aristotle has already observed...* it would probably get a chuckle, since we might refer to a contemporary in that way but not an ancient philosopher. It would extend the notion of "recent" in a rather comical way.

Comment: "I'm afraid Plato has beaten you to it." Right. He had a head start of several thousand years.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Thanks a lot for your efforts 1) _Aristotle has already observed that_ is an unexceptional phrase in contemporary philosophical texts, there is nothing unusual in its tense: _ Kant says that... Hegel is trying to explicate..._ and so on. 2) I have understood that **already** has rather different connotations in English comparatively to its Russian counterpart. I've got to think it through.

Comment: Log: The phrase *Aristotle has already observed* is idiomatic only when the "now" (the temporal *origo* the present perfect is used in relation to) is  much more encompassing than the **now** of the man-on-the-street. For the student of Western philosophy, the "now" is all of western philosophy. The philosopher treats Aristotle as a contemporary.  The philosopher's "now" is the historian's "then" .  So it is a rather *exceptional* phrase indeed.  Also, when working with texts it is common to use the present to refer to the author's words.

Comment: But that is not what you have asked about. You have asked about how " to mention a person whose times is compared to ours", though I don't think you mean "compared".  And **times** there is treated as a plural, BTW. Specifically the question is about how to use the word **already** when the reference is to something ancient.  We would not say *The Druids have already built Stonehenge.*  Those Druids no longer exist.

Answer (score 2):

Since the question is becoming clarified with comments, a second crack.

The question does **not** seem to be how to refer to an ancient author when discussing his or her texts.  We can and do say "Aristotle **writes** that ...".
Rather, the question seems to be how to use the word **already** of something that happened in ancient times and at the same time to be using **already** in relation to the *present*.

We would not say

> The Druids have already built Stonehenge. <sup>NO</sup>
>
> Neanderthals have already interbred with Homo-Sapiens. <sup>NO</sup>

—not unless we were following a time-line of human development, and in that case **already** would not be used in relation to *now* but in relation to a point on that time-line.

Those sentences are well-formed but they misuse the present perfect and the word **already** on a semantic level, for those Druids and Cro-Magnons no longer exist but the present perfect casts them as our contemporaries.

We don't use the word **already** in relation to *now* when speaking of something that happened in ancient times. We only use it in relation to another past time, and when doing so we use the past perfect:

> The Mayans had already made significant astronomical discoveries long before the advent of the telescope.

or in relation to something recent with the present perfect:

> I've already drunk too much coffee today, so none for me, thanks.

Comment: But that's the usual vehicle in any narrative—to use present tenses to enhance suspense, immediacy and the like.

Comment: Yes, but you're not asking about the use of the present when speaking of a text. You're asking about the use of **already**, a temporal relation.

Answer (score 1):

The expression in the question is mostly correct correct:

> The notion that the Earth is a sphere has been around since ancient times.

You can also use the past perfect tense in combination with the adverb "already"

> By the 4th century BC, Aristotle had already observed that the length of a shadow varies between Greece and Egypt.

Other useful adverbs include "before" or "after"

> Even before Ptolemy, Aristotle had observed that the Earth is spherical.

Or "prior to"

> Prior to Copernicus most people thought the Earth was at the centre of the solar system.

But, as observed in a comment, there are a very wide range of ways of talking about relative time in English.

Comment: These are good but the point is to expess it as concisely as possible. In Russian one can express it with the help of only one word: _**Уже** Аристотель заметил, что..._ or _**Ещё** Аристотель заметил, что..._

Comment: Express what? You haven't written a full sentence.  Anyway you shouldn't always expect the features that can be expressed in one word have to be one word in English.  Can Russian distingish between "the dog" and "a dog"?

Comment: There is no need for a fuller sentence here—for any Russian the meaning is immediately grasped no matter what follows. If that's impossible in English—so, that's that.

Comment: Do you mean "Already Aristotle observed that" is an idiom, used to to mean "that is already well known." (in which case see another answer). In which case your question is not about expressing temporal relations.

Comment: No, no - I meant Russian locutions I've mentioned: Уже Аристотель заметил, что... or Ещё Аристотель заметил, что... Either way, in English or in Russian, there is no way to avoid expressing temporal relations imo.

Comment: There is no need to express the past time in an explicit relationship with the present, @Mv Log.  You can say *Aristotle wrote*.  The simple past is silent with respect to the present in a way that the present perfect is not silent: *Aristotle has written ...*    The present perfect casts Aristotle as relevant to now.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo  But that's the point—to express the past time in an explicit relationship with the present or, more precisely, the other way around = the present to the past and to emphasize that mentioning the very person who already did it then in the past: _It was already observed by Aristotle that..._ something along these lines.

Comment: Then I think "already" with either a present or past perfect is correct, as in my second example. The "one word" you want is "already", but you need to choose an appropriate tense.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not looking for ways to speak about temporal relations generally, but are looking for ways to express the idea "this idea isn't new", we cannot really say it in a single word.

> *That's nothing new*.  Already back in the 5th century BCE ...
>
> *There's nothing new about that*. Already back in the 5th century BCE ...
>
> *Oh yeah, what else is new?* They knew that back in the 5th century BCE ...
>
> *That's old hat*.  Already back in the 5th century BCE ...
>
> *Yeah, yeah*. Already back in the 5th century BCE ..

old hat (colloquial) = not interesting because it has been known for rather a long time (but usually measured in weeks or months, not millennia)

*oh yeah, what else is new?*  is a colloquial rhetorical question expressing sarcasm that the other person thought the idea was new or that information was news.  It's a line that Martin Scorsese could put in Joe Pesci's mouth.

*yeah, yeah* = I've heard it all before.